# Is there a graph without a $K_5$ subdivision that has a chromatic number of $5$?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs, graph-minors, forbidden-subgraphs

The Four Color Theorem states that a planar graph requires at most four colors to be proper colored.

The Kuratowski's Theorem states that a graph is planar if, and only if, it doesn't have a subgraph which is a subdivision of either $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$.

We can conclude then that a graph that requires at least five colors to be proper colored must have a subgraph which is a subdivision of either $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$.

$K_5$ is, itself, a graph that requires five colors, but $K_{3,3}$ requires only two. So my question is: is there a graph that requires at least five colors to be colored that doesn't have a subgraph which is a subdivision of $K_5$? (Of course, that would force it to have a subdivision of $K_{3,3}$)

I know it's equivalent to the Four Color Theorem that "graphs that require five colors must have a minor of a $K_5$", but I don't think that answers my question, since subdivisions are just a particular case of minor. I might be wrong, though.

Comment: https://hog.grinvin.org/ViewGraphInfo.action?id=26  Discussion: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2666350/123905

Comment: @EricTowers that graph do have a $K_5$ subdivision.

Comment: I don't see it.  I see plenty of unfinishable almost-$K_5$ subdivisions.

Comment: I think I recall this as one of the cases of the Hajós conjecture.

Comment: @EricTowers To find a $K_5$ subdivision in that graph, let $u_1, u_2$ be the two middle vertices, and $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5$ be the outside vertices in order around the cycle. Then $\{u_1, u_2, v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ can be the key vertices of the subdivision. The only missing edge is $v_1 v_3$, and it can be replaced by the path $(v_1, v_5, v_4, v_3)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unknown whether such a graph exists. Originally, Hajós conjectured that for all $k$, all graphs with no subdivision of $K_{k+1}$ are $k$-colorable. It is now known that for $k\ge 6$, this conjecture is false. For $k=3$, the conjecture is proven; for $k=4$ (this question) and $k=5$, it is still open.

One of the most recent papers with partial progress on this conjecture seems to be [Wheels in planar graphs and Hajós graphs](https://doi.org/10.1002/jgt.22687) by Qiqin Xie, Shijie Xie, Xingxing Yu, and Xiaofan Yuan. Here (as in many other papers) a Hajós graph is defined to be a minimal counterexample to the conjecture: a graph $G$ such that

1. $G$ contains no $K_5$ subdivision;
2. $G$ is not $4$-colorable;
3. Subject to 1 and 2, $|V(G)|$ is as small as possible.

The ultimate hope, of course, is to prove that $G$ cannot exist - or to find an example. To make partial progress, researchers try to prove more and more properties of Hajós graphs, which should make it easier to reach a contradiction, or to construct a Hajós graph.